# Disable dimming animation of UIModalTransitionStyle.coverVertical

Tags: ios, swift

My modal window opens from bottom to top with smooth animation. When it is open, the part of the screen not occupied by the modal window is dimmed. My problem is that the dimming also appears with animation. I want dimming to appear instantly while modal window still appear with animation.

```
if let subjectsListViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SubjectsListViewController") as? SubjectsListViewController {
            subjectsListViewController.delegate = self
            
            subjectsListViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
            subjectsListViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.coverVertical
        
            
            present(subjectsListViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```